# Coefficient in Formal Power Seies

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the coefficient of $z^k$ in
$$\frac{\sum_{n\geq1} z^n/n}{1-z}$$

---

Is my solution correct?
Write the above sum as:

$$\sum_{n\geq1} z^n/n\cdot\sum_{n\geq0} z^n$$

To get the coefficient of $z^k$ we simply see we can get k as a product of (coeff of z in first sum)(coeff of z in second sum): $(1,k-1)...(k,0)$. But the second sum has 1 as coefficient always.

So, Coefficient of $z^k$ in the whole sum is just :
$$\sum_{n\geq1}^k1/n$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

More generally if $a(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $b(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n$ then:

$$a(x)b(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n;\\c_n=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ib_{n-i}$$

The convergence in general of $\sum c_nx^n$ is only known for $x$ absolutely convergent in both $a(x)$ and $b(x),$ but it can be bigger than that, for example $a(x)=\frac1{1-x},b(x)=1-x.$

In your case, $a_0=0,$ so there are $n$ terms for $c_n$ rather than $n+1.$

This is called the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two series.

Your results, $\sum_{n=1}^k  \frac1n,$ are often written as $H_k,$ and are called the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).